# How to break this limit?

Tags: pine-script

This is a [limt](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html#limits) when using label.new.
So has some way for break this limit?
I just achieve the follow goal.
[image]

The following code can achieve goals but has limits.

```
label.new(bar_index, high, '1', textcolor=color.red, style=label.style_none)
label.new(bar_index, high, '2\n', textcolor=color.green, style=label.style_none)
label.new(bar_index, high, '3\n\n', textcolor=color.blue, style=label.style_none)
```

Comment: There's no way to break the limit. Are you sure that you need more than 50 labels?

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure need.I juse want to print multi-line text on the top of a bar with different color. Do you have any other suggestions ？ The following code can  achieve goals but has limits.
label.new(bar_index, high, '1', textcolor=color.red, style=label.style_none)
label.new(bar_index, high, '2\n', textcolor=color.green, style=label.style_none)
label.new(bar_index, high, '3\n\n', textcolor=color.blue, style=label.style_none)

Comment: Do you know the values when current bar is being handled? Maybe you can use background color for such color? E.g. create few plots `plot(high + N points)` and then via fill change background? And the text put via only one label: "1\n2\n3'". I don't see better approach, but this one is not the best one.