# How do I ask a good question?why is error when use plotshape?

Tags: pine-script

```
var x = '123'
x := x + '211'
plotshape(true, style=shape.labelup, color=close>open ?color.green:color.red, text= x, location=location.belowbar)
```

will has error 'line 39: Cannot call `plotshape` with arguments (literal bool, style=const string, color=series[color], text=string, location=const string); available overloads: plotshape(series[bool], const string, input string, input string, series[color], input integer, series[integer], const string, series[color], const bool, const string, input integer, string) => void; plotshape(fun_arg__, const string, input string, input string, fun_arg__, input integer, series[integer], const string, fun_arg__, const bool, const string, input integer, string) => void'

Answer (score 5):

`plotshape()`'s `text=` parameter requires a *const string* and you are using a *series string* argument:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_plotshape

[image]

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
barColor = close > open ? color.green : color.red
a = "Bar is\n" + (barColor == color.green ? "green" : "red")
if bar_index % 10 == 0
    label.new(bar_index, na, a, yloc = yloc.belowbar, color = barColor, textcolor = barColor, style = label.style_triangleup)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Can i modif this code and then print 'ab' in chart ?
var a = 'a'
a:= a + 'b'

plotshape(true, style=shape.labelup, color=close>open ?color.green:color.red, text= a, location=location.belowbar)

Comment: No. But you can use `var a = 'a' + 'b'` because then variable `a` will be of type *const string* so known at compile time. Note than you can plot series text using a label, which will give you more flexibility provided you don't need more than the last ~50 labels showing. Added a code snippet to my answer.

Comment: Thanks！I has try to used this way and then has a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222261/how-to-break-this-limit).
I seem to be stuck in an endless loop.